# How to understand the codebase if I miss some source codes?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, reverse-engineering

I have a Java codebase that has some classes which are only available in compiled (?) form. I do not have the sources for them.

Is it even possible to understand what they do? They sometimes pass a compiled class between themselves. Could I somehow see what propeteries the objects have ( by looking at their variables ) and understand the whole process?

Or is it impossible? I always hit a impassible spot when I try to understand what a unsourced class does.

Any tips or help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read their documentation? Seriously, A library that comes without source, and without documentation, shouldn't be used at all.

Comment: Best way is to search for their javadoc. You can associate javadoc in IDE with respective jars. Other way would be use a decompiler.

Comment: It might be possible to figure out some of what the classes do from decompiling and reading the bytecode, but you would have to learn a huge amount about the JVM specification and still would have an incomplete picture.  This may be more trouble than it's worth, and a lot more time than you probably have.

Comment: Maybe I could see what the unsourced object receives and what it returns later on? Running it multiple times on edge cases should let me paint a bigger picture. I then could try to write my own class that would replace it? I think it's the only choice especially if I am time constrained.

Comment: It's a niche software for biochemistry simulation and it has incomplete documentation. It's just that some parts are unsourced. Most has the documentation but the most important bits don't unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If you are desperate, you could try '[jad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAD_%28JAva_Decompiler%29)'.